# Redux, callback after synchronous action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to figure out how to properly implement a callback after a synchronous action is called, and the relevant react components has been updated. What I'm trying to do can be compared with scrolling to, and focusing a newly created todo.

What I'm currently doing:

```
// in Entries Component
createEntry() {
  this.props.actions.createNewEntry(key);

  setTimeout(() => {
    // accessing updated DOM
    this.scrollToAndFocus(key);
  });
}
```

It works, but it feels very brittle and hackish. There must be a better way?

Comment: maybe ... in componentDidMount, if it's a new todo - scroll to that node ?

Answer (score 6):

As answered in the comments, the right hook in the component lifecycle is `componentDidUpdate`. From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate):

> Invoked immediately after the component's updates are flushed to the DOM. This method is not called for the initial render.

Therefore your component becomes:

```
createEntry() {
    this.props.actions.createNewEntry(key);
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scrollToAndFocus(key);
}
```

Be aware that if you further modify the DOM in `componentDidUpdate`, then you should implement a stop condition, otherwise you would end up in an endless loop. This can be done either

- by overriding [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate), if the stop condition depends on the current and future values of `props` or `state`.
- in `componentDidUpdate`, if it depends on some DOM properties, e.g., `document.activeElement`